# PropTypes.node gives an unexpected mismatch error in React

Tags: reactjs, semantic-ui-react

I defined class like that:

```
import { Popup } from 'semantic-ui-react'

const FamilyLink = ({ family, fields, PopupClass = Popup }) => React.createElement(PopupClass, {...})

FamilyLink.propTypes = {
  PopupClass: PropTypes.node,
}
```

`Popup` from `semantic-ui-react` is a `React Component`: 
https://github.com/Semantic-Org/Semantic-UI-React/blob/62d2feda4c89bb604ab39e3ae5d44f4b78769e7b/src/modules/Popup/Popup.js

Then in another component I called the `FamilyLink` like that:

```
class PopupWithModal extends React.PureComponent {...}

<FamilyLink family={family} fields={FAMILY_FIELDS} PopupClass={PopupWithModal} />
```

So, now while rendering I would expect `React.PureComponent` to be passed as `PopupClass` which should be fine, in my view, given the following definitions of the `React.PropTypes`:

https://reactjs.org/docs/typechecking-with-proptypes.html#proptypes

However, neither `PropTypes.node`, nor `PropTypes.elementType` are working, but only `PropTypes.func` giving me an error in console:

> Warning: Failed PropType: Invalid prop `PopupClass` supplied to `FamilyLink` expected a `ReactNode`

Why is it that? I understand that both `Component` and `PureComponent` are functions as can be seen here:

https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/0cf22a56a18790ef34c71bef14f64695c0498619/packages/react/src/ReactBaseClasses.js

However, I would prefer `PropTypes` to limit my input parameter only to the `React` component and not to any other arbitrary functions. Besides, from my understanding it is supposed to work.

> Update

If we update it to `PropTypes.elementType` we will get the following error:

> Warning: Failed prop type: FamilyLink: prop type `PopupClass` is invalid; it must be a function, usually from the `prop-types` package, but received `undefined`

With `PropTypes.func` it does not give ***any*** errors.

Comment: `elementType` is the correct type, it should be working

Comment: I substituted it and updated the question.